# Subsonic 5 Minute Demo newbie problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I have looked at the "Subsonic 5 Minute Demo", and got my data objects generated from the database after some initial problems. I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 and my project is, as in the demo, an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application.

So, I've written this code in my HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to Food Recipe Web!";

    //lets get some data
    var db = new FoodRecipeWeb.Data.FoodRecipeWebDB();
    var recipes = from r in db.Recipes
                  select r;

    return View(recipes);
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <ul>
    <%foreach (var recipe in Model)
      { %>

      <li><%= recipe.Name %></li>

    <% } %>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

This is quite like the demo, but when I try to look at the page, I get this message:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Source Error:
Line 6:      <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
Line 7:      <ul>
Line 8:      <%foreach (var recipe in Model)
Line 9:        { %>
Line 10:
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your View needs to know about the Model.

Change it from:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"

Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Recipe>>"
```